# Does it make sense to use async programming to send emails to a single smtp server?

Tags: asynchronous, smtp

I'm developing a service that pops multiple emails from a queue and attempts to send them using SMTP via a single server.

I'm wondering if async programming can provide any real benefits vs normal synchronous?

Since SMTP is a sequential protocol, my initial thoughts is that async will not provide any real value.

Comment: This question boils down to "do you want to do anything else while you're waiting for the mail to be sent?"

Comment: @Amadan Well, not really, this service's only job is to send the email and report the result back.
But I'd like to send other emails from queue while current one is being sent (maybe I should use usual threads instead).